# Google Cloud App Engine Deploy Fail (Django)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my app but I keep getting this error on the website:

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

The error logs for this are:

```
2021-07-15 12:36:04 default[20210715t122912]  [2021-07-15 12:36:04 +0000] [20] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20)
2021-07-15 12:36:04 default[20210715t122912]  [2021-07-15 12:36:04 +0000] [23] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-07-15 12:36:04 default[20210715t122912]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker      worker.init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process      super().init_process()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app      mod = importlib.import_module(module)    File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed    File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>      from booking.wsgi import application    File "/srv/booking/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I already have a main.py file:

**main.py**

```
from booking.wsgi import application

app = application
```

I also have an app.yaml file and these are the contents:

```
runtime: python39

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT booking.wsgi
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: it says in the error `no module named 'django'` are you sure you've installed django and all your packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is you're not installing the requirements on Google App Engine (GAE), as Jameel Hamdan pointed out.

The fix is to put all your requirements in a `requirements.txt` file as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies).

The other thing is that you are using an entrypoint in the `app.yaml`. There's 2 issues with this:

1. Your entrypoint is incorrect. Considering the way you've set it up, your entrypoint should be `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`. This way you tell `gunicorn` to look for the `app` object in the `main.py` file.
2. Since you're using a non-default entrypoint, you'll need to make sure `gunicorn` is in your `requirements.txt` as described in the [GAE docs for entrypoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup). I know it's a bit implicit with this sentence: *App Engine will also automatically add the gunicorn to your requirements.txt file if you don't specify the entrypoint field.* But I am sure you need `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt`.

---

**Sidenote**

Since you're likely not using a `requirements.txt` file, you're likely also not using a `virtualenv` for your local development. You should **always** use a `virtualenv`. See the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Better to get used to doing this now, so you will be doing this without thinking for next projects.

Note that this is also recommended in the [GAE docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies) for the `requirements.txt` I linked earlier.

---

**EDIT**

Try changing your `app.yaml` to [the default](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#understanding_the_code) `app.yaml` for Django:

```yaml
runtime: python39

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm now getting an error that says, there is no module called booking. Booking is the name of the app in the django project. Is there a way to access the main.py file?

Comment: I edited my answer, if that doesn't help please go through the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) to see what's different between that setup and yours...